# API access to Library members?

Tags: content, contentworkspace

I found an existing question which hasn't been answered in a while.

We need to programmatically add members to content libraries - we have nearly 2000 of them. However, there doesn't seem to be any object exposed which maps "members (users/groups) to the ContentWorkspace object.

Aside from manually updating each library, is there a way to bulk add members across multiple libraries?

Comment: and current libs don't aren't permissioned by some group or role?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? We need to add a new member (actually a public group) to 2000 existing libraries.

Comment: just wondering if you had an existing public group you could exploit by adding members to it?

Comment: Ah, no... but it's a good idea. Unfortunately, each has a one public group per library, so there are currently 2000 of these groups. This is actually all a workaround for a larger code problem we are having that's preventing us from migrating from content to chatter feeds in batch. The code works fine in regular execution, but it fails as soon as it's in batch, so instead of migrating the nearly 500K content files we have, we are kludging together a content workaround.

Comment: I did just find that i can programmatically update the parentID of the ContentDocument record, so I'm going to move all of the content into a handful of libraries that have the correct permissions on them, barring  limitations on how many files can be in a library which i feel likely to run into.