# In Apex, how do I know if my user can contribute content to a particular library?

Tags: apex, contentversion, public-group, libraries

Is there a way to discover if the current user can publish content to a specific Library using either Apex or Javascript?

### Use Case

I have a shared library (DeveloperName = `Shared_Forms`) that many users have access to.  A subset of those users can publish content there.  In my current page, I want a link to the library to appear if a user can publish to that library.

### Problem

A User can publish content to that library because they have a `ContentWorkspaceMember` record with `ContentWorkspacePermission.PermissionsAddContent = true` or because they are in a Public Group (`Group`) which has a `ContentWorkspaceMember` record with `ContentWorkspacePermission.PermissionsAddContent = true`.  As you probably know, figuring out Group Membership properly is not a straightforward task

> For example, a User can have a Role (Subdivision lead) which is a subordinate of another Role (Division lead) which has a related Group of type RoleAndSubordinates and that Group is a member of a Group that's a member of my current Group).

And let's not even talk about the `doesIncludeBosses` option.

### Question

In order to avoid recursive SOQL queries and redoing Salesforce's whole permissions model, I was wondering if there's a way I can access any of the following, as they would all get me very close to my goal:

- Can logged in User X publish content in Library L? (this is my ultimate goal)
- Who are all the users who have `PermissionsAddContent` in Library L?
- What Groups is logged in User X in (recursively)?
- Who are all the users who have ContentWorkspacePermission  P in Library L?

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166396/getting-members-of-a-content-library

Comment: there's alway the `try and publish - if success, then rollback; if exception, then you know user can't publish` technique

Comment: @cropredy That sort of coding makes me feel dirty, but I find Salesforce leaves me with no other option for many permission-y things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly a hack but is "future proof" to any additional complexities that SFDC might add to the library permissioning model or until a built-in method exists to tell you what you need.

In the Apex ...

```
public Boolean isPublishable() {
  Database.Savepoint sp;
  try {
    sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    ... insert some strawperson doc into library of interest
    Database.rollback(sp); // worked, must be publishable, roll it back
    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {return false;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I settled on. It makes my skin crawl. I wish there was a more robust API in Apex that could answer these domain-specific questions. Especially around permissions and sharing.